# What weapons, poisons, or other items help reduce enemy Will saves?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, saving-throw, illusion

I am working on an illusionist build for a friend and hoping to find some items that he could use to weaken enemy Will saves against his illusion spells.

He is playing a sorcerer with a few levels of cleric... because he loves Orcus... he's an interesting character.

Comment: The question (not just the title) should *also* limit answers to weapons and poisons and should explain what's meant by *tactics.* (Since most Will saving throw-reducing techniques are magical item and spell-based, I think limiting the question to weapons, poisons, and maybe whatever *tactics* means makes the question sufficiently narrow.)

Comment: Okay, now that it includes feats it's probably too broad. A new question like *What feats make an illusionist's illusions better?* or whatever is a fine standalone question. Changing *this* question to *only* mundane and magical items probably limits it sufficiently so it isn't too broad. Lumping everything together, however, is just too darn big of list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Poisons:

- [Insanity Dust](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#poison):  DC 15 inhaled poison, deals 1d4 initial Wis damage, 2d6 secondary Wis damage.  Pricey at 1500 GP, but nice that it can be thrown with a touch attack.
- Doubt Bomb (Fiend Folio 68):  Also used as a ranged touch attack, 1d6 initial/1d6 secondary Wis damage, cheaper at 500 GP but still not cheap.

Both of these options inherit the weaknesses of all poisons:  Their DCs aren't very high, it's hard to get them higher because they don't scale off of your level or ability scores, and lots of things are flat-out immune to poison.

### Other Items:

- The *shaken* condition inflicts a -2 penalty to all saving throws, so any item that helps you apply fear effects will make enemies less likely to save against illusions.  The *Fearsome* and *Menacing* armor properties (MIC) are nice in this regard because they apply *shaken* even when your enemy makes their saving throw.  Of course, they don't apply to enemies immune to fear or mind-affecting.
- The *sickened* condition also inflicts a -2 penalty to saves.  You can use a Stench Stone (MIC p. 186) to force a save against this, or use spells/feats (which are beyond the scope of this question).
- The Mindcrusher weapon property (MIC p. 39) deals Wis damage on hit to creatures without power points (including non-psionic creatures, which is probably most of them).  Unfortunately, Will DC 17 negates, and expensive at a +2 property.
- The DMG provides [guidelines](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm) for creating and pricing custom items, including items whose powers are based on existing spell effects.  These rules explicitly require DM sign-off, and are notorious for being poorly balanced, but if they're allowed at your table, they provide lots of ways to apply penalties to Will saves via items.  Look into items of spells like [Mind Fog](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mindFog.htm) or [Prayer](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/prayer.htm).